# How do I stop a span going to next line in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting this behaviour on my bootstrap website[image]

It looks fine at full width but when I make the window narrower or it is view on an iPad, the span10 (content area) goes to a new line. I can solve it by making the span10 a span 9 but this leaves a gap to the right of it.

This is how I'd like it to look on iPad and narrow computer windows:

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code? You can try to apply `float:left` to it.

Comment: Could you maybe post your code to http://www.bootply.com/new?

Comment: [Bootstrap `span*` classes](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) are `float:left` styled and will fall to a new line if there isn't enough room for them. So, very simply, the 2 elements are too wide combined to fit side-by-side within their parent element. But, how exactly to fix that depends on the code, especially any custom CSS that affects their widths and margins.

Comment: One quick fix might be to add a min-width to your contract me <div> (style="min-width:600px;"), I believe this is a little trick I have done to deal with this problem in the past.